# Using reduce to query object data in an array and reformat it

Tags: javascript, reduce

I have a data structure that looks like the following:

```
var deliveries = [{
    location: "Chicago",
    units: 10
}, {
    location: "San Francisco",
    units: 5
}, {
    location: "Miami",
    units: 2
}, {
    location: "San Francisco",
    units: 13
}, {
    location: "San Francisco",
    units: 2
}, {
    location: "Chicago",
    units: 16
}, {
    location: "Miami",
    units: 1
}];
```

I want to be able to query any of the cities and get the number of times they appear in the data structure and the total number of units for that city.

The code I have to do this is as follows:

```
function getData(arr, city) {
    var numberOfdeliveries = 0;
    var totalUnitsDelivered = 0;


    arr.forEach(function(val, index, arr) {
        if (val.location === city) {
            numberOfdeliveries += 1;
            totalUnitsDelivered += val.units

        }
    })
    return "number of deliveries: " + numberOfdeliveries + ". Total units:" + totalUnitsDelivered
}

getData(deliveries, "San Francisco"); // number of deliveries: 3. Total units:20
```

This works fine.

However, I am curious if it is possible to use reduce to return an array that has all of the city numbers and all of their total units.

In other words the end result should look like this:

```
[{
    "Chicago": 2,
    units: 26
}, {
    "San Francisco":20,
    units: 5
}, {
    "Miami": 2,
    units: 3
}];
```

The furthest I've been able to get is to return an object with the number of times the cities appear.

```
var deliveries = [{
    location: "Chicago",
    units: 10
}, {
    location: "San Francisco",
    units: 5
}, {
    location: "Miami",
    units: 2
}, {
    location: "San Francisco",
    units: 13
}, {
    location: "San Francisco",
    units: 2
}, {
    location: "Chicago",
    units: 16
}, {
    location: "Miami",
    units: 1
}];



var answer = deliveries.reduce(function(obj, val, index, all) {
    if (!obj[val.location]) {
        obj[val.location] = 1
    } else {
        obj[val.location]++
    }

    return obj

}, {})



console.log(answer);  //{ Chicago: 2, 'San Francisco': 3, Miami: 2 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a result array and a hash table for the reference to the element in the result array.

```js
var deliveries = [{ location: "Chicago", units: 10 }, { location: "San Francisco", units: 5 }, { location: "Miami", units: 2 }, { location: "San Francisco", units: 13 }, { location: "San Francisco", units: 2 }, { location: "Chicago", units: 16 }, { location: "Miami", units: 1 }],
    groups = deliveries.reduce(function (hash) {
        return function (r, a) {
            if (!hash[a.location]) {
                hash[a.location] = {};
                hash[a.location][a.location] = 0;
                hash[a.location].units = 0;
                r.push(hash[a.location]);
            }
            hash[a.location][a.location]++;
            hash[a.location].units += a.units;
            return r;
        };
    }(Object.create(null)), []);

console.log(groups);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you plan on making this query more than once would be more practical to map your data to a hashmap object using cities as keys

```
var cities ={};
deliveries.foreach(function(item){
   var cityObj = cities[item.location] ?  cities[item.location] :{units:0, count:0}

   cityObj.units += item.units;
   cityObj.count ++;

});
```

Would produce something like:

```
{ "Chicago" :{units: 10, count:2},
  "San Francisco":{units: 5, count:1}
}
```

Then when you need the values:

```
var city="Chicago",
    units = cities[city].units;
```

Comment: This doesn't work. There is a typo in foreach and the end result doesn't produce what you typed.

Answer (score 0):

Technically **Nina** answered the question but **charlietfl** idea of using a hash map I think is better ( even though his/her code doesn't seem to work). So I figured out how to create a hash map using reduce. I awarded the answer to to Nina just because it was "correct" but here is what I came up with.

```
var deliveries = [{
    location: "Chicago",
    units: 10
}, {
    location: "San Francisco",
    units: 5
}, {
    location: "Miami",
    units: 2
}, {
    location: "San Francisco",
    units: 13
}, {
    location: "San Francisco",
    units: 2
}, {
    location: "Chicago",
    units: 16
}, {
    location: "Miami",
    units: 1
}];

var answer = deliveries.reduce(function(obj, val, index, all) {
    if (!obj[val.location]) {
        obj[val.location] = {
            times: 1,
            units: val.units
        }
    } else {

        obj[val.location].times += 1;
        obj[val.location].units += val.units;
    }



    return obj

}, {});

console.log(answer);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Map objects for grouping.

```js
var deliveries = [{ location: "Chicago", units: 10 }, { location: "San Francisco", units: 5 }, { location: "Miami", units: 2 }, { location: "San Francisco", units: 13 }, { location: "San Francisco", units: 2 }, { location: "Chicago", units: 16 }, { location: "Miami", units: 1 }, ];

var result = [];
deliveries.reduce(
 (cities, delivery) => cities.set(delivery.location, [...(cities.get(delivery.location) || []), delivery]), new Map
).forEach((deliveries, city) => {
 var r = {};
 r[city] = deliveries.length;
 r.units = deliveries.reduce((s, c) => s + c.units, 0);
 result.push(r);
})
console.log(result);
```